# jsonreaderexception unexpected character encountered

Tags: c#, json, angularjs

I have a web project using angular and C#.
In a C# controller, I want to read in the contents of a local json file that is used for testing.

This is the code that I run to read the JSON from my working directory.

```
string path = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/testing/testData.json");
JObject jsonData = JObject.Parse(path);
string jsonString = jsonData.ToString();
List<orResult> result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<orResult>>(jsonString);
return result;
```

The JSON can be seen here. [Json](https://jsfiddle.net/hg6zjff1/)

When I run the app, I get the following error.

> An exception of type 'Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException' occurred in
>   Newtonsoft.Json.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: Unexpected character encountered while parsing
>   value: M. Path '', line 0, position 0.

When I hover look at the path variable, it points to the right spot. If I copy and paste the path variable in to my browser, I see the JSON. The error is something with Parsing the data or something... I have no idea. Need help!

I've looked at other solutions on Stack and none of them resolved my problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`JObject.Parse()` expects the actual JSON content (string), not a path.

Your JSON is really an array so you could use `JArray.Parse()` instead. Also, converting JSON string to `JObject` and then back `ToString()` is really not adding any "value" here.

---

This should do it.

```
string json = File.ReadAllText(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/testing/testData.json"));
var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<orResult>>(json);
```

Comment: Using [`JToken.ReadFrom()`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/ReadJson.htm) one can stream directly from the file without needing to load an intermediate string representation.

Answer (score 0):

You are attempting to deserialize the translated **path** ("c:\whatever\...\testing\testData.json") that [MapPath](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms524632(v=vs.90).aspx) returns, i.e. not the *content* of the file.

Try something like this instead:

```
JObject jsonData = JObject.Parse(File.ReadAllText(path));
```

... but then again, there is no need to use `Parse()` as you don't need the `JObject`. Just deserialize directly to a `List<orResult>`:

```
var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<orResult>>(File.ReadAllText(path));
```